# utilizing Auto-desk forge for automated file conversion to Navisworks .nwc format

Tags: autodesk-forge

looking to leverage **autodesk-forge** in a new way.  We are exploring the automation of "appending" files to Navisworks from AutoCad, Revit, 3D Studio Max, SktechUp, and other common team file formats.  Basically, a cloud-based, automated version of NavisworksExporters20XX.

Any guidance / help is appreciated. . .

Thx

DBW

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Design Automation API for Revit can help in that case, but it's not supported currently unfortunately, see restrictions here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/#design-automation-api-for-revit

Comment: Thanks Eason - we'll see if AutoDesk can come up with a better option